# How to fetch only few columns from an abstract entity in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an abstract entity which have around 140 columns and i have mapped all the columns. I have a scenario where i have to create an entity extending this abstract entity and for my requirement I need just the data of 40 column attributes than 140. I need just to read the data no need of persisting it.

When I use the extended entity in my Java Service Implementation, I am getting all the data. The problem is when i read more than 1000 records there is an impact on performance as it is loading all the 140 column data.

So, Is there any way or any annotation I can use not to read the data of other 100 columns in my extended entity?

```
  @MappedSuperClass
  public abstract class Base{
   //140 variable declarations like
   private string name;
   .....
   //getters and setters
  }


  @Entity
  @Table("TableName")
  public class A extends Base{
  //need just the 40 columns data from base 

  }
```

I thought not reading that remaining data might improve performance in case i have many records. 
NOTE :  I can't write another abstract class because we are using only one abstract entity for one table.

Comment: You have to do the opposite. Declare Base `Class (not abstract class)` with 40 fields, then extend that Base Class in `Class A`

Comment: I already have abstract classes for all the tables. So if I have to use anything I have to extend from this abstract entities, This is how our application design is. So I can't create it like you said.

Comment: If you're using Hibernate Criteria, then you have to use Projections to fetch only particular columns.

Comment: I have to filter the records on the service side. So basically i will get all records and do all the processing in the java side. I was just looking for any annotation i can use to annotate the fields from the entity side.
Like we have @transient when not to persist on database. So do we have anything like that for not to read from database?

Comment: JPA allows the use of setting mappings to be lazily fetched which might help, and then use entity graphs to control what are prefetched in specific queries.  http://www.radcortez.com/jpa-entity-graphs/ has a good explanation

Comment: Your model and description though doesn't make sense.  Why extend the base class but only want 40 of the 140 properties filled with data?  Why bother with the 100 extra property overhead if they are not relevant to class A?

Comment: @Chris I am basically looking for an annotation which will lazily load the remaining attributes which stops unnecessary reading of other columns. I have looked into @Basic(fetch=fetchType.lazy) on not required attributes. Unfortunately it not working because it is meant only to be a hint to the persistence provider to help the application achieve better performance. But hibernate is not respecting it.

Comment: I still don't understand the point of your inheritance model, as an A should expand on Base, not reduce it.  If you can't use a provider that supports functionality you want, you might try using JPA constructor queries instead.  "Select new A(a.id, a.att2, ....a.att40) from A a" for instance.  What is returned is unmanaged.  Otherwise